# Httpd setting up permission

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I saw a lot of quesiton about this but nothing solve my problem.
I've got a symlink in /var/www/site that point to /home/user/Development/site.
This is my virtual host :

```
VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.localhost
    ServerAlias site.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/web
    <Directory /var/www/site/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I set up the permission for the parent direcotry so :

```
chmod o+x /home /home/user /home/user/Development /home/user/Development/site
```

Then when i try to access to http://site.localhost i get :

> Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:57908] AH00529:
>   /var/www/site/web/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check
>   htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that
>   '/var/www/site/web/' is executable, referer:
>   http://site.localhost/

So I setup 644 permission to .htaccess :

```
chmod 664 /home/user/Development/site/web/.htaccess
```

But I still continue to receive the same error.

This is my .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Can someone help me to understand where i'm wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem, and maybe could help someone.
The problem is

> SELinux is preventing httpd from read access on the file ...

So to solve the problem just set httpd_read_user_content to 1 :

```
setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
```